# how to upload csv file to mysql using jsp and servlet

Tags: mysql, jsp, csv, servlet-3.0

I am trying to upload CSV file to mysql using below code,

Myjsp.jsp ;

```
<form action="CSVFileUploadSERvlet" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

CSVFileUploadSERvlet.java :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

/*String getPath = request.getParameter("file");
        System.out.println(getPath);*/ //I know this return null

        File filename1 =new File("/home/raptorjd4/Desktop/CheckingCSVFile.csv");

        String tablename ="Checking_table";

        String query=null;
        PrintWriter obj1 = response.getWriter();
        try {
            if(filename1.exists())
            {

            conv = new Connectivity();
            con = conv.setConnection();
            st = con.createStatement();
            query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"" + filename1 + "\" INTO TABLE " + tablename + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES";

            st.executeUpdate(query);

            obj1.println("Row (1) inserted");


            }
            else
            {
              obj1.println("File not found...!");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

If i give file path directly `File filename1 =new File("/home/raptorjd4/Desktop/CheckingCSVFile.csv");` then file uploading to DB successfully.but how to get uploaded file path and do like this `File filename1 =new File(UploadedFilePath);`.

Someone change my code to upload csv file to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in your jsp form tag add enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
//In servlet, you need to get content type first.
String contentType = request.getContentType();
//now this contentType contains multipart data
if (contentType.toLowerCase().contains("multipart")) {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
String data= null;
do {

    // skip first header lines which contains the header data such as Content-Disposition or Content-Type
        data = reader.readLine(); 
    } while(!(data.toLowerCase().contains("content-type")));

    while( (data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(data.startsWith("--")) {
            continue;
        }                   

        if (!data.toLowerCase().contains("webkitformboundary")) {
            if (!data.toLowerCase().contains("content-disposition")) {
                System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++ data: "+data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And in your jsp form tag add <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: if i do your changes then System.out.println(data); displays : Content-Type: text/csv

Comment: what is that "dataLine" in if(dataLine.startsWith("--")) ?

Comment: sorry its data not dataLine